# JPEG-Decompression on RAW image in python

Tags: python, jpeg, compression, python-imageio, rawimage

When I try to JPEG-Decompress (old-style JPEG compression, not JPEG-LS and not JPEG2000) the RAW data, I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raw-reader.py", line 766, in <module>
    raw_image_data = imageio.imread(io.BytesIO(raw_packed_image_data))
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py", line 206, in imread
    reader = read(uri, format, 'i', **kwargs)
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py", line 129, in get_reader
    return format.get_reader(request)
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/format.py", line 168, in get_reader
    return self.Reader(self, request)
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/format.py", line 217, in __init__
    self._open(**self.request.kwargs.copy())
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/plugins/pillow.py", line 398, in _open
    pilmode=pilmode, as_gray=as_gray)
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/plugins/pillow.py", line 122, in _open
    self._im = factory(self._fp, '')
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 780, in jpeg_factory
    im = JpegImageFile(fp, filename)
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 102, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 339, in _open
    handler(self, i)
  File "/home/ian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 166, in SOF
    raise SyntaxError("cannot handle %d-bit layers" % self.bits)
SyntaxError: cannot handle 14-bit layers
```

The RAW data in the image is 14-bit JPEG data, and imageio isn't able to read it. When I tried using pillow, it didn't even recognize the data as JPEG. My question now is: How can I decompress the data without writing my own JPEG decompressor, while keeping in mind that the data is 14 bits?

My code:

```
import io
import imageio

allbytes = open("raw_data.dat", "rb").read()

raw_packed_image_data = allbytes
raw_image_data = imageio.imread(io.BytesIO(raw_packed_image_data))
```

The file `raw_data.dat` is a file containing purely the RAW-Image data compressed with JPEG. Link to [raw_data.dat](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1DXhrXU2IAxldhvxwp3otX43JEnl0ofQH&export=download)

Comment: Please add the code, not only the stack trace.

Comment: @sophros I added my code.

Comment: I believe we need a bit more. Have you read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If not, please do so and apply here.

Comment: e.g. nobody but you has an idea what `raw_tags` might be. The code *excerpt* is not self-contained.

Comment: @sophros I added an MCVE!

Comment: Perfect. It seems that you have come across a PIL library limitation or an image format issue (are you sure the image is not corrupted)?

Comment: The image is not corrupt, since I was able to open the file in several other programs. What I need now is an alternative method/library to decode the JPEG data. If you have any tips, you are welcome to suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_data.dat` is a `JPEG Lossless, Nonhierarchical` file with 2 frames and a precision > 8-bit, a very rare format.

The [imagecodecs](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) package can read the file (assuming that the `_imagecodecs` Cython extension is present):

```
>>> from imagecodecs import jpegsof3_decode
>>> data = open('raw_data.dat', 'rb').read()
>>> image = jpegsof3_decode(data)
>>> image.shape
(3528, 2640, 2)
>>> image.dtype
dtype('uint16')
```

The LEADTOOLS SDK should also be able to read the file (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue can be solved using a different library to load the image. Similar underlying issue has been posted here [How to combine 3 high range JPEG2000 images into single RGB one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157201/how-to-combine-3-high-range-jpeg2000-images-into-single-rgb-one). You can use something along these lines:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img_red = mpimg.imread('raw_data.dat')
```

Then you can use the read bitmap for further manipulation as if it was loaded via PIL/Pillow/imageio.

Comment: I edited my question to specify which type of JPEG decompression I need (in TIFF, it is compression index 6). Also, when I try using `mpimg`, I get `ValueError: invalid PNG header` when I use BytesIO and `OSError: cannot identify image file 'raw_data.dat'` when I read from file.